# imagecreatefrompng not found

Tags: php, captcha

The following PHP code does not work correctly;

```
<div style="text-align:center"><img src="scripts/captcha/index.php?<?php echo session_name()?>=<?php echo session_id()?>" style="vertical-align:middle" /> <input type="text" name="keystring"><br /><span class="fontsm">(word verification)</span></div><br />
```

It's for a CAPTCHA verification. It's hosted with GoDaddy. On the old server, it worked. It's been transferred to a new server, and it doesn't work.

The PHP spits out the following HTML code;

```
<img src="scripts/captcha/index.php?PHPSESSID=331f5041b67145685c5401104c602876" style="vertical-align:middle" />
```

So for some reason the IMG element fails to load the image.

When I type;

```
http://c-compiler.com/scripts/captcha/index.php?PHPSESSID=331f5041b67145685c5401104c602876
```

into MSIE, it says;

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
imagecreatefrompng() in
/home/ccompiler12/public_html/scripts/captcha/kcaptcha.php on line 49
( ! ) Error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefrompng() in
/home/ccompiler12/public_html/scripts/captcha/kcaptcha.php on line 49
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  354104  {main}( )   .../index.php:0
2   0.0002  355304  KCAPTCHA->KCAPTCHA( )   .../index.php:33

So it's not finding function imagecreatefrompng.
```

The help page for imagecreatefrompng is at;

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php
```

How do I get this function working? It seems to be the absence of this
particular function which is the issue.

The GD extension is installed.

```
Is imagecreatefrompng part of GD? If not, which extension are they part of?
```

Comment: Do a `phpinfo()` to double check that GD is installed

Comment: Yes, that function is part of GD. Installed != enabled, so check `phpinfo()` to make sure.